# Remove the text before input using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup inside our SharePoint online page:-

```
<span dir="none">
<span class="ms-formdescription">Type the Web address:

<a id="ProjectLinkToOMS_5205a8ac-b318-479c-b47d-81d61d06d244_$UrlControlId" aria-describedby="ProjectLinkToOMS" href="javascript:TestURL('ProjectLinkToOMS_5205a8ac-b318-479c-b47d-81d61d06d244_$UrlFieldUrl')" target="_self">Link To OMS</a>
<br>
</span>
<input dir="ltr" type="text" value="http://test.com" id="ProjectLinkToOMS_5205a8ac-b318-479c-b47d-81d61d06d244_$UrlFieldUrl" aria-describedby="ProjectLinkToOMS" aria-label="Type the Web address:" class="ms-long" style="display: none;">
<br>
```

where there is a text `Type the web address`.. so not sure how i can write a jQuery code to remove the text (the text which is just before the `a` with id `ProjectLinkToOMS_....`)?

Comment: Looks like some PHP leftovers. Check out server side first.

Comment: @V.Volkov this is a SharePoint page which i can not control the generated markup.. i can only write jQuery code to modify the markup..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have one on the page, which you probably don't.

```
var element = $(".ms-formdescription");  // this will need to change
```

Once you have the element, it should be straightforward.  This will work assuming you have no dynamic events added to the href.

```
element.html(element.html().replace("Type the web address", "");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,, now the issue is that the span itself does not have an id.. so i can not directly select the span.. what i can do is that i can reach the span text from the `a` link following it.